# Javascript - RegExp - Replace character not surrounded by letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex like this:

```
str.replace(/([^a-zA-Z])e([^a-zA-Z])/g, "$12.718281828459045$2")
```

The regex isn't doing what I want, and I don't know why.

So what I want to to do, is to replace all "e"'s in a string that's not connected to any A-z letter with 
"2.718281828459045", what's wrong in my regex?

```
"2e" -> "2e", should be: "22.718281828459045"
"2e2" -> "22.7182818284590452", working
"2*e*e*2" -> "2*2.718281828459045*e*2", should be "2*2.718281828459045*2.718281828459045*2"
```

Comment: `2e` will not work as there is nothing after `e`.

Comment: @vks How about "2*e*e*2"?

Comment: You can solve this with a negative lookahead. Shown working here: http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/2

Comment: @Alxandr post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the first one does not match because there is nothing after the `e`, thus it has to check for an `e` followed by something that isn't a letter **or** end of input. However, the third example doesn't work because in `2*e*e*2` the first match is `*e*`, thus both `*` are "consumed", so what's left of the string is only `e*2`. This obviously doesn't fix the problem.

What can be used in stead is a negative lookahead. They are written as `a(?!b)` in regex and (in this case) means an `a` not followed by a `b`. So we make the regex into `([^a-zA-Z])e(?![a-zA-Z)`. However, this still does not match the simple string `e`, because there is nothing in front of it. In something that's not JavaScript we could use a negative lookbehind, though js doesn't support this, so rather just change it to `(^|[^a-zA-Z])e(?![a-zA-Z])`.

The meaning is: Find any `e` that is at the beginning of the string, or after something that's not a-z or A-Z, and is not followed by an a-z or A-Z.

Here is working demo: http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/3 (note, I replaced with `<input>` though, because it's simpler to see that the replacing is right.)

Comment: But this one takes less space than a positive, does that make any difference?

Comment: So this should be (^|[^a-zA-Z])e(?![a-zA-Z]|$) instead of (^|[^a-zA-Z])e(?![a-zA-Z])?

Comment: No, the negative lookahead deals with end of string it seems. You can see that here: http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/5

Comment: So /(^|[^a-zA-Z])e(?![a-zA-Z])/g === /(^|[^a-zA-Z])e(?=[^a-zA-Z]|$)/g

Comment: Yeah, it would seem so. There's more than one way to Rome.

Answer (score 0):

The second set of parentheses *consumes* that part of the string for the regex.  What that means is that the remaining string `e*2` does not match because that `e` is not preceded by the non-alphanumeric character.  You can use a lookahead instead which does not consume.

```
"2*e*e*2".replace(/([^a-zA-Z])e(?=[^a-zA-Z])/g, "$12.718281828459045")
```

Comment: ("2*e").replace(/([^a-zA-Z])e(?=[^a-zA-Z])/g, "$12.718281828459045") -> "2*e", should be "2*2.718281828459045"

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex -

```
Regex   - ([^a-zA-Z])?(?:e(?:.*e)?)([^a-zA-Z])?
Replace - $12.718281828459045$2
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zN0zI8/2)

Comment: ("e*e").replace(/([^a-zA-Z])?(?:e(?:.*e)?)([^a-zA-Z])?/g, "$12.718281828459045$2") -> "2.718281828459045", should be "2.718281828459045*2.718281828459045"

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
find:    /(^|[^a-zA-Z])e(?=[^a-zA-Z]|$)/g
replace: $12.718281828459045
```

.

```
str.replace(/(^|[^a-zA-Z])e(?=[^a-zA-Z]|$)/g, "$12.718281828459045")
```

Comment: e*e -> ${1}2.718281828459045${1}2.718281828459045, not working?

Comment: @Murplyx: I've forgotten the `g` (global) modifier. see my edit

Comment: Is there any difference between this: http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/2 as Alxandr posted and yours?

Comment: Not really, he uses negative look ahead and I use positive lookahead. I haven't seen his answer before I posted mine.

Comment: Yes, we were probably working on it in parallel. I also had negative lookbehind at the beginning, though js didn't support that.

Comment: He wrote a comment for it, but it takes less space though is that better in anyway?

Comment: @M42 Do you still need the `$` at the end, when you use the lookahead?

Comment: @Alxandr: Yes, I do because it may have a letter or end of line.

Comment: @Alxandr Which one should I use?

Comment: @M42 No you don't (at least not according to my tests, but there might be something I'm missing), cause the lookahead takes care of that: http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/4

Comment: @M42 Oh, sorry. JS doesn't handle newline as a end of string kind of deal. I'm used to regex in other languages. You are right, you need `|$`.

Comment: @M42 Which one should I use?

Comment: @Murplyx: TThe one you understand the best. It's just a question of taste

Answer (score 0):

try with `/([^a-zA-Z])?e(?![a-zA-Z])/g`
And '$12.718281828459045' for replacement.

Using negative look ahead, and an optional previous alpha character as there is no lookbehind in JS (that I know of).